# I dont know why my materials aren't visible, nodes aren't working

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm not sure why I can't fully edit my material in the materials tab. I tried using nodes, and I have "use nodes" clicked and that isn't working either. Help please[image]

Comment: That looks like you are using an older version of Blender and have the render engine set to the old 'internal' engine.  Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have your render engine set to Workbench:

[image]

Set it to Cycles or Eevee to be able to edit your materials again.

Comment: you are correct! Thank you much